# Problem with yasnippet in emacs + autex

Tags: emacs, auctex, auto-completion

I am newbie in Emacs + AucTeX and trying to get familiar with auto-complete mode in editing LaTeX. Auto-complete is a fantastic attribute, but I don't understand the follow problem:

Auto-complete can help me when I use <kbd>TAB</kbd>

> \usepac
>   \usepackage[opt1, ...]{Package}

But if I regret and try to use backspace to cancel it

> usepackage[opt1, ...]{

the command line shows

> "Exist the snippet first !" and this line becomes undeletable.

How can I do?

Comment: I use Command+z to roll back on my mac. Maybe Ctl+z on window.

Comment: Have you tried C-g to cancel your snippet?

Comment: I've tried, C-g doesn't work. "Exist the snippet first!" message still show up.

Answer (score 1):

yasnippet and auto-complete mode are similar but distinct packages. You can use them simultaneously, and both will complete your input after pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>. What you describe happens when you expand a (ya)snippet that waits for further input. If you change your mind midway, first abort the current action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>), then use undo repeatedly to roll-back the input. Undo is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> on my machine. As per default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> will not work on Linux but rather send emacs to the background (console) or iconify its window (X).

Comment: On a GNU/LInux system `undo` can be accessed by `C-x u` or `C-S--` (Ctrl + Shift + -) even if no transient mark is set.